# Prevent Automatic Horizontal Scroll in TreeView

Tags: wpf

Whenever a node is selected in my treeview, it automatically does a horizontal scroll to that item.  Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Handle the [RequestBringIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.requestbringintoview.aspx) event and set Handled to true, and the framework won't try to bring the item into view.  For example, do something like this in your XAML:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

And then this in your code-behind:

```
private void TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to preserve vertical scrolling, and only prevent horizontal scrolling?

Comment: for @MatthewPirocchi and others who have the same issue: looks like I found a solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/34269542/692829

Comment: A new, simpler, solution to allow vertical scrolling without changing the horizontal scroll offset (with no unwanted side effects), see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225940/prevent-automatic-horizontal-scroll-in-treeview/34269542#42238409

Answer (score 20):

I managed to solve the problem using the following:

```
<TreeView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
   <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter, AncestorLevel=1}}" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemsPanel>
</TreeView>
```

I bind the width of the StackPanel which renders the ItemsPanel here, to the ActualWidth of ContentPresenter in the TreeView.

It also works nice with the "hacked" Stretching TreeView by: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2008/08/05/wpf-a-stretching-treeview.aspx (I modified that solution not to remove grid column, but to change Grid.Column property of the first Decorator element from 1 to 2).

Answer (score 11):

To offer a slightly simplified version of @lena's answer:

To scroll vertically while preserving the horizontal scroll position, and with no unwanted side effects, in the XAML, add event handlers for RequestBringIntoView and Selected:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView"/>
            <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="OnSelected"/>
            ...
```

In the code behind, add two event handlers:

```
private void TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    // Ignore re-entrant calls
    if (mSuppressRequestBringIntoView)
        return;

    // Cancel the current scroll attempt
    e.Handled = true;

    // Call BringIntoView using a rectangle that extends into "negative space" to the left of our
    // actual control. This allows the vertical scrolling behaviour to operate without adversely
    // affecting the current horizontal scroll position.
    mSuppressRequestBringIntoView = true;

    TreeViewItem tvi = sender as TreeViewItem;
    if (tvi != null)
    {
        Rect newTargetRect = new Rect(-1000, 0, tvi.ActualWidth + 1000, tvi.ActualHeight);
        tvi.BringIntoView(newTargetRect);
    }

    mSuppressRequestBringIntoView = false;
}
private bool mSuppressRequestBringIntoView;

// Correctly handle programmatically selected items
private void OnSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TreeViewItem)sender).BringIntoView();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Excellent approach. There are two things you might improve:
1. To avoid magic numbers, I would suggest using `double.NegativeInfinity` and `double.PositiveInfinity` as the horizontal bounds in `newTargetRect`
2. Since `TreeViewItem` contains all its child `TreeViewItems` within its bounds, this  implementation may cause unnecessary vertical scrolling. I would suggest using ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).ActualHeight instead of `tvi.ActualHeight`

Answer (score 7):

Matthew, I manged to preserve vertical scrolling, and only prevent horizontal scrolling by restoring the horizontal position after a scroll caused by the RequestBringIntoView event .

```
private double treeViewHorizScrollPos = 0.0;
private bool treeViewResetHorizScroll = false;
private ScrollViewer treeViewScrollViewer = null;

private void TreeViewItemRequestBringIntoView( object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e )
{
    if ( this.treeViewScrollViewer == null )
    {
        this.treeViewScrollViewer = this.DetailsTree.Template.FindName( "_tv_scrollviewer_", this.DetailsTree ) as ScrollViewer;
        if( this.treeViewScrollViewer != null )
            this.treeViewScrollViewer.ScrollChanged += new ScrollChangedEventHandler( this.TreeViewScrollViewerScrollChanged );
    }
    this.treeViewResetHorizScroll = true;
    this.treeViewHorizScrollPos = this.treeViewScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
}

private void TreeViewScrollViewerScrollChanged( object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e )
{
    if ( this.treeViewResetHorizScroll )
        this.treeViewScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset( this.treeViewHorizScrollPos );

    this.treeViewResetHorizScroll = false;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. using e.Handled=true; did not work for me, but yours definitely does it!

Comment: Tried many of the solutions here, and this was the only one that worked without nasty side effects.  A better solution would be for Microsoft to simply fix this undesirable behavior.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. I needed to prevent horizontal scroll but preserve vertical scroll. My solution is to handle `OnRequestBringIntoView` method as I want it to behave. I created a `ResourceDictionary` for a `TreeViewItem` and added `EventSetters` for `OnSelected` and `OnRequestBringIntoView` methods.

MyResourceDictionary.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"  x:Class="Resources.MyResourceDictionary" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Key="treeitem" >
        <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView"  Handler="OnRequestBringIntoView"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="OnSelected"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MyResourceDictionary.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Resources
{
    partial class MyResourceDictionary:ResourceDictionary
    {
        public MyResourceDictionary()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnRequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true; //prevent event bubbling
            var item = (TreeViewItem)sender;
            TreeView tree = GetParentTree(item) as TreeView;
            if(tree!=null)
            {
                var scrollViewer = tree.Template.FindName("_tv_scrollviewer_", tree) as ScrollViewer;
                if (scrollViewer != null)
                {
                    scrollViewer.ScrollToLeftEnd();//prevent horizontal scroll
                    Point relativePoint = item.TransformToAncestor(tree).Transform(new Point(0, 0));//get position of a selected item 
                    if (relativePoint.Y <= scrollViewer.ContentVerticalOffset) return;//do no scroll if we select inside one 'scroll screen'
                    scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(relativePoint.Y);//scroll to Y of a selected item
                }
            }
        }

        private DependencyObject GetParentTree(DependencyObject item)
        {
            var target = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
            return target as TreeView != null ? target : GetParentTree(target);
        }

        private void OnSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //handle programmatically selected items
        {
            var item = (TreeViewItem)sender;
            item.BringIntoView();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following solution is more simple and fully tested and more compatible, You don't need to calculate and change scrollbar offset, what you need is moving horizontal scrollbar to left, since "RequestBringIntoView" event routing strategy is bubbling, you simply need to do it on last item reached event. 
Name scrollViewer control "_tv_scrollviewer_"

```
<TreeView>
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView"/>
```

On code behind:

```
    private void OnRequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (TreeViewItem)sender;
        if (item != null)
        {
            // move horizontal scrollbar only when event reached last parent item
            if (item.Parent == null)
            {
                var scrollViewer = itemsTree.Template.FindName("_tv_scrollviewer_", itemsTree) as ScrollViewer;
                if (scrollViewer != null)
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, (Action)(() => scrollViewer.ScrollToLeftEnd()));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Best answer in my opinion.

Comment: Definitely best, fastest solution. Just a question: where have you read about "_tv_scrollviewer_"?

Answer (score 1):

@lena's solution of preserving vertical scrolling worked best for me. I've iterated on it a little bit:

```
    private void TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
    {
        var treeViewItem = (TreeViewItem)sender;
        var scrollViewer = treeView.Template.FindName("_tv_scrollviewer_", treeView) as ScrollViewer;

        Point topLeftInTreeViewCoordinates = treeViewItem.TransformToAncestor(treeView).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        var treeViewItemTop = topLeftInTreeViewCoordinates.Y;
        if (treeViewItemTop < 0
            || treeViewItemTop + treeViewItem.ActualHeight > scrollViewer.ViewportHeight
            || treeViewItem.ActualHeight > scrollViewer.ViewportHeight)
        {
            // if the item is not visible or too "tall", don't do anything; let them scroll it into view
            return;
        }

        // if the item is already fully within the viewport vertically, disallow horizontal scrolling
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

What this does is let the ScrollViewer scroll normally if the item isn't already in the viewport vertically. However for the actual "annoying" case (where the item is already visible), it sets e.Handled to true, thus preventing horizontal scrolling.

Comment: In my testing, this solution only works if the TreeView is not scrollable vertically (the content is vertically contained within the visible boundaries of the TreeView).

Answer (score 0):

I had a DataGrid that I wanted to do the same operation on and used POHB's answer mostly.  I had to modify it for my solution.  The code is shown below.  The datagrid is a 2 x 2 datagrid with the first column being thin and the second being very wide (1000+).  The first column is frozen.  I hope this helps someone out. -Matt

```
  public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
  {
      private ScrollContentPresenter _scrollContentPresenter;
      private ScrollViewer _scrollViewer;
      private double _dataGridHorizScrollPos = 0.0;
      private bool _dataGridResetHorizScroll = false;

      public MyUserControl()
      {
          // setup code...
          _dataGrid.ApplyTemplate();

          _scrollViewer = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(_dataGrid);
          _scrollViewer.ScrollChanged += new ScrollChangedEventHandler(DataGridScrollViewerScrollChanged);

          _scrollContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ScrollContentPresenter>(_scrollViewer);
          _scrollContentPresenter.RequestBringIntoView += new RequestBringIntoViewEventHandler(_scrollContentPresenter_RequestBringInputView);              
      }

      private void DataGridScrollViewerScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          if (_dataGridResetHorizScroll)
          {
              _scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(_dataGridHorizScrollPos);
          }
          // Note: When the row just before a page change is selected and then the next row on the  
          // next page is selected, a second event fires setting the horizontal offset to 0
          // I'm ignoring those large changes by only recording the offset when it's large. -MRB
          else if (Math.Abs(e.HorizontalChange) < 100)
          {
              _dataGridHorizScrollPos = _scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
          }

          _dataGridResetHorizScroll = false;
      }

      public T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
      {
          if (depObj != null)
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
              {
                  DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

                  if ((child != null) && (child is ScrollViewer))
                  {
                      // I needed this since the template wasn't applied yet when 
                      // calling from  the constructor
                      (child as ScrollViewer).ApplyTemplate();
                  }

                  if (child != null && child is T)
                  {
                      return (T)child;
                  }

                  T childItem = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
                  if (childItem != null) return childItem;
              }
          }
          return null;
      }

      private void _scrollContentPresenter_RequestBringInputView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
      {
          _dataGridResetHorizScroll = true;
      }
```