# Prevent Automatic Horizontal Scroll in TreeView is not working. MVVM, XAML approach

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, treeview

Whenever a node is selected in my treeview, it automatically does a horizontal scroll to that item. [I've found the way to disable this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225940/prevent-automatic-horizontal-scroll-in-treeview).  If I use this code in code behind, it works perfectly:

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
         <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView"/>
      </Style>
   </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>

private void TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

However, if I use MVVM, I cannot disable horizontal scroll to the item:

My window:

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewWpfApplication.MainWindow"
    . . . . .  
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:ei=http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions>
  <TreeView Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Background="Green">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="RequestBringIntoView">
                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="RequestBringIntoView_Handler" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers> 

<TreeView>
     <TreeViewItem Header="---Level 1" >
       <TreeViewItem Header="--- Level 2.1" >
          <TreeViewItem Header="--- Level 3.1" >
          </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
     </TreeViewItem>  
     <TreeViewItem Header="Level 2.3" />        
   </TreeView>
 </Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public void RequestBringIntoView_Handler(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;         
}
```

**Why cannot I stop automatic horizontal scroll to the item by MVVM approach?**

Comment: XAML* approach.  MVVM is a pattern for separation of concerns,  XAML is the tool you use to make the UI.

Comment: have you tried setting some break point to check if the handler is fired?

Comment: @KingKing , yes, I have. The handler is fired. However, handler does not prevent horizontal scroll to the item. However, it works perfectly in code behind. I cannot figured out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: there is one different thing I can see here is the working code setting the event handler for all sub treeView items (excluding the TreeView itself) while the second seems to setup the event handler for just the TreeView itself, I'm not so sure if the `RequestBringIntoView` event can be bubbled up from the TreeViewItem but looks like it is not.

Comment: @KingKing could you write some XAML code for treeviewitem? Please. I've tried to implement XAML, but I caught errors that 'nested property cannot contain triggers'. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can always loop through all `TreeViewItem` of the `TreeView` and clone each `TriggerBase` from `Interaction.Triggers` attached on the `TreeView` before attaching each cloned one to the `Interaction.Triggers` of each `TreeViewItem`.

I'm so disappointed about Microsoft, that name has made me proud of and been my endless inspiration for many years since I started beginning to learn how to program. But frankly speaking there are many things Microsoft made us disappointed. Your code should have actually worked fine. Why? I've tried it and the event `RequestBringIntoView`  actually bubbles up from `TreeViewItem` to `TreeView`. And in fact when you add the event handler on `TreeView` directly, you'll see the event handler is fired OK. But the very equivalent form of setting handler using `Interaction` does not work that way. That's so terrible. It's obvious that it's designed to setup event handler in MVVM way but it's so limited.

I had to make a work-around in which we use a custom attached property to allow to set the `Interaction.Triggers` in Style. However I have to say that it's not very pretty. You need to explicitly declare an `Array` of `TriggerBase` (I've done something like this before but never found a better solution for this). Next you need to use a proxy to bind `TargetObject` for `EventTrigger` (because we put the trigger in an Array and it's detached from visual tree).

Here is the code for the custom attached property:

```
//add some using alias like this first
//using i = System.Windows.Interactivity;
public static class InteractionX 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TriggersProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Triggers", typeof(i.TriggerBase[]), 
          typeof(InteractionX), new PropertyMetadata(triggersChanged));
    public static i.TriggerBase[] GetTriggers(DependencyObject o){
        return o.GetValue(TriggersProperty) as i.TriggerBase[];
    }
    public static void SetTriggers(DependencyObject o, i.TriggerBase[] value)
    {
        o.SetValue(TriggersProperty, value);
    }
    static void triggersChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var triggers = e.NewValue as i.TriggerBase[];
        var currentTriggers = i.Interaction.GetTriggers(o);
        currentTriggers.Clear();
        foreach (var t in triggers)
        {
            t.Detach();
            currentTriggers.Add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the XAML:

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeView.Resources>
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Key="proxy" Value="{Binding}"/> 
  </TreeView.Resources>
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
         <Setter Property="local:InteractionX.Triggers">
                <Setter.Value>            
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type i:TriggerBase}">
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="RequestBringIntoView">
                            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="bringIntoViewHandler" 
                             TargetObject="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </x:Array>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>   
      </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

It appears that the `Interaction.Triggers` set on `TreeViewItem` can handle bubbling-up `RequestBringIntoView` from the descendant TreeViewItems but as I said it's a pity that setting that on `TreeView` does not work.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are the master of programming! You are  Hero!:)