# How to Prevent Automatic Vertical Scrolling in UWP TreeView

Tags: windows, uwp

Whenever an item is selected in my TreeView, it automatically does a vertical scroll and positions in the middle. How to prevent this automatic scrolling in UWP TreeView?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225940/prevent-automatic-horizontal-scroll-in-treeview) StackOverflow answer on preventing horizontal scrolling in WFP but I can't find any

`<EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="TreeViewItem_RequestBringIntoView"/>`

event in UWP.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the scrolling behavior that you mentioned? What scrolled, the content of the TreeView or the nodelist of the TreeView?

Comment: nodelist of TreeView as after scrolling I selected a node in Treeview. Then it automatically moves to the middle of the TreeView.

Comment: I made a simple TreeView sample with many nodes in UWP to test. But I can't reproduce the behavior that you mentioned. When I select the node that is not in the middle, the nodelist will not move. Could you please share the code snippet that could reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake that it happen only make text bigger on windows 11 is enable. Then a flickering occurs and the scroll move a little bit up.

Comment: I also made a demo Treeview application and it's work fine in my end also.

Comment: Do you mean you changed the text size in the Settings? I tried the set the text size as the biggest and test again. but it still does not scroll automatically.

Comment: Hi @RoyLi-MSFT I think I have found my actual problem. In ScrollViewer I have TreeView and also some other items. When going down and selecting a specific item then the automatic scroll happens. It will not go to the middle but a scroll happens.

Comment: I think I have the similar issue as this issue suggests. Link: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/597

Comment: In this thread, a ScrollViewer Jumps to Top-most but in my end ScrollViewer jump. And it is visible.

Comment: Have you tried DuncWatts's workaround in the link you posted? Setting `IsTabStop="true"`?