# WPF TreeView - scroll expanded items into view

Tags: wpf, treeview

I'm trying to write a custom WPF/MVVM TreeView control that will automatically scroll (as many as possible) of the child items into view when a parent item is expanded.

I've found this post, [WPF TreeView - How to scroll so expanded branch is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241367/wpf-treeview-how-to-scroll-so-expanded-branch-is-visible), but it seems that only works when the tree items actually descend from TreeViewItem.

My Tree Item class is just a plain C# object - along the lines of Josh Smith's blog http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode, which are lazy loaded in the IsExpanded property setter in the Tree Item class.

Stepping into the OnExpand event handler, I can see that the original source is a TreeViewItem (created by the framework behind the scenes) which has my tree item object in the header field. This TreeViewItem has only 1 visual child, a grid, which in turn has 3 visual children, ToggleButton, Border and ItemsPresenter.

Does anyone have a hint as to how I can get the corresponding visual components for my child items, on which I can then call BringIntoView()?

Answer (score 3):

Found a very nice behavior which scrolls the selected item into view, located here:

This unfortunately doesnt cater for when the item is expanded, but can be modifed according to your exact requirements. If you need any help just let me know.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF

Comment: Highly recommended using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Five years is a very long time in programming terms ...

I returned to this question recently after being awarded the badge for 2500 views. It just happens that I had made a post on my blog with the solutions to these issues a short while before - http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/.

I know that link-only answers are not generally approved of on stackoverflow, so I'll post the key elements here too.

1) The helper for TreeViewItem contains two attached properties, one to scroll the selected item into view, and the other to scroll as many children as possible into view when an item is expanded.

```
public static class perTreeViewItemHelper
{
    public static bool GetBringSelectedItemIntoView(TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
    {
        return (bool)treeViewItem.GetValue(BringSelectedItemIntoViewProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBringSelectedItemIntoView(TreeViewItem treeViewItem, bool value)
    {
        treeViewItem.SetValue(BringSelectedItemIntoViewProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BringSelectedItemIntoViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "BringSelectedItemIntoView",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(perTreeViewItemHelper),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, BringSelectedItemIntoViewChanged));

    private static void BringSelectedItemIntoViewChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!(args.NewValue is bool))
            return;

        var item = obj as TreeViewItem;

        if (item == null)
            return;

        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
            item.Selected += OnTreeViewItemSelected;
        else
            item.Selected -= OnTreeViewItemSelected;
    }

    private static void OnTreeViewItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
        item?.BringIntoView();

        // prevent this event bubbling up to any parent nodes
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    public static bool GetBringExpandedChildrenIntoView(TreeViewItem treeViewItem)
    {
        return (bool)treeViewItem.GetValue(BringExpandedChildrenIntoViewProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBringExpandedChildrenIntoView(TreeViewItem treeViewItem, bool value)
    {
        treeViewItem.SetValue(BringExpandedChildrenIntoViewProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BringExpandedChildrenIntoViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "BringExpandedChildrenIntoView",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(perTreeViewItemHelper),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, BringExpandedChildrenIntoViewChanged));

    private static void BringExpandedChildrenIntoViewChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!(args.NewValue is bool))
            return;

        var item = obj as TreeViewItem;

        if (item == null)
            return;

        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
            item.Expanded += OnTreeViewItemExpanded;
        else
            item.Expanded -= OnTreeViewItemExpanded;
    }

    private static void OnTreeViewItemExpanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;

        if (item == null)
            return;

        // use DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, so that we wait for all of the UI elements for any newly visible children to be created

        // first bring the last child into view
        Action action = () =>
        {
            var lastChild = item.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(item.Items.Count - 1) as TreeViewItem;
            lastChild?.BringIntoView();
        };

        item.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

        // then bring the expanded item (back) into view
        action = () => { item.BringIntoView(); };
        item.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

        // prevent this event bubbling up to any parent nodes
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

2) The style for TreeViewItem includes these properties

```
<Style x:Key="perExpandCollapseToggleStyle"
       TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid Width="10"
                      Height="10"
                      Background="Transparent">
                    <Path x:Name="ExpanderGlyph"
                          Margin="1"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Data="M 0,3 L 0,5 L 3,5 L 3,8 L 5,8 L 5,5 L 8,5 L 8,3 L 5,3 L 5,0 L 3,0 L 3,3 z"
                          Fill="LightGreen"
                          Stretch="None" />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ExpanderGlyph" Property="Data" Value="M 0,0 M 8,8 M 0,3 L 0,5 L 8,5 L 8,3 z" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ExpanderGlyph" Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="ExpanderGlyph" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="perTreeViewItemContainerStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">

    <!-- Link the properties of perTreeViewItemViewModelBase to the corresponding ones on the TreeViewItem -->
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />

    <!-- Include the two "Scroll into View" behaviors -->
    <Setter Property="vhelp:perTreeViewItemHelper.BringSelectedItemIntoView" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="vhelp:perTreeViewItemHelper.BringExpandedChildrenIntoView" Value="True" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"
                                          MinWidth="14" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  Grid.Column="0"
                                  ClickMode="Press"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  Style="{StaticResource perExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" />

                    <Border x:Name="PART_Border"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                          Margin="0,2"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          ContentSource="Header" />

                    </Border>

                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="1" />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <!--  Use the same colors for a selected item, whether the TreeView is focussed or not  -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource perTreeViewItemContainerStyle}" />
</Style>
```